# Posting a multi-part form using Invoke-WebRequest generates a content-type exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I’m trying to create a function to upload data using multi-part forms.

Normally, I’d use the `Form` parameter, but .Net has [an issue w/ file names that include diacritical marks](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16237) (e.g. résumé.pdf).

As a result, I'm building my own.  I'm using Bamboo HR's [Upload Employee File](https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/upload-employee-file-1) method as a guide for what needs to be included in the post.

The function:

```
$GUID = (New-Guid).Guid
$boundary = "------$GUID----"

# I've tried this w/ and w/o the `"` around the boundary text
$ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`""

$Item = Get-Item -Path $Path

$Headers['Content-Length'] = $Item.Length

$Parts = @()

$Parts += 
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"fileName`"

{0}
" -f $Item.Name

$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path);
$fileEncoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString($fileBytes);

$Parts += 
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"{0}`"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{1}

" -f $Item.Name, $fileEncoded

$Parts += 
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"share`"

{0}
" -f ( $Share ? 'yes' : 'no' )

$Parts += 
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"category`"

{0}
" -f $CategoryId

$LF = "`r`n";

$Body += "$boundary$LF"
$Body += $Parts -join "$boundary$LF"
$Body += "$boundary$LF"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers $Headers -ContentType $ContentType
```

When the function is run, `Invoke-WebRequest` returns this error:

> The cmdlet cannot run because the -ContentType parameter is not a valid Content-Type header. Specify a valid Content-Type for -ContentType, then retry. To suppress header validation, supply the -SkipHeaderValidation parameter.

I've added the `SkipHeaderValidation` but without success.

When run with a file named `LoremIpsum.rtf` with this content:

```
Lorem ipsum
```

The content-type:

```
multipart/form-data; boundary="------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----"
```

The body:

```
------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

LoremIpsum.rtf
------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="LoremIpsum.rtf"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2580
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww11520\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Lorem ipsum\
}

------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="share"

yes
------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"

22
------ea1b6b8d-1399-4d1e-be72-8cafa00434d1----
```

Is this a just a problem w/ how I've specified the `Content-Type` header or something else?

Comment: I've never done multi-part forms before so someone else may have a more helpful answer but you should note that ```-ContentType ``` simply adds a content type header to your request. You can omit that entirely and just add another header with the key 'Content-Type' and a value of 'multipart/form-data'. 
According to MSDN docs you may also need to specify some sort of boundary in the header as well like so: ```Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=something```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working code.

```
$uri = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{0}/v1/employees/{1}/files" -f $company, $employeeID
$pdf = Get-Item $filepath
$fileName = $pdf.Name
$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($pdf);
$fileiso = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1').GetString($fileBytes);
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$LF = "`n"

$bodyLines = (
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="category"',
    '',
    "$category",
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"',
    '',
    "$($fileName)",
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="share"',
    '',
    "yes",
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename=$($fileName)",
    'Content-Type: application/pdf',
    '',
    "$fileiso",
    "--$boundary"
) -join $LF

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary" -UseBasicParsing -Body $bodyLines
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You don't have to add [UseBasicParsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#-usebasicparsing) since it has been deprecated. Beginning with PowerShell 6.0.0, all Web requests use basic parsing only.